# TKinter leaving borders around widgets

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

When I put a button in on a colored background TKinter leaves this weird white box around the widget. For example the code below:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x100+300+300")
root.configure(bg="red")
button = Button(root, text="Connect", highlightthickness=0)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

What can I do to get rid of the white spacing?

Comment: Widgets occupy rectangular areas of the screen.  On Windows, this code shows the black text on a light gray rectangle with raised relieve (the defaults on Windows).  There is no inner rounded rectangle.  The vertical padding is about the same (C is about 1/3 of height.  The horizontal padding is much less (less that the width of C).  These details are system specific.  PS: This is a great mcve (minimal, complete, verifiable example), which I could copy, paste, and run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The extra border is caused by the `highlightthickness` attribute. The default value is 1 (one); set it to zero to remove the border. This border shows when the button has keyboard focus.

However, it appears you're running this on OSX. OSX buttons are a bit less configurable than on other platforms. Setting highlightthickness to zero won't help. The best you can do is set `highlightbackground` to the same color as your background so that it blends in.

Comment: He appears to have highlightthickness set. No white border on linux, maybe it's a mac issue?

Comment: Yeah, the OP edited the code to include `highlightthickness` after I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been plaguing Macs for years.  But as of Python 3.7 it's safe-ish to install from Python.org instead of Homebrew.  This problem disappears when Python is installed from Python.org instead of running the Homebrew version.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for something similar in `ttkbootstrap`, you can use:

```
button = Button(root, text="Connect", takefocus=0)
```

This should work on OSX too.