# Grey border around tkinter widgets (not using canvas)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am experiencing issues with a Python 3 tkinter program I'm working on.

I am running macOS Sierra.

When running the app, every widget has a grey border around it.

Is there any way to remove this?

**Screenshot of the border:**

[image: A screenshot showing 3 widgets, each with a border]

**Here's the code:**

```
# Item list
itemlist=Treeview(root)
itemlist.heading("#0", text="Item Name")
itemlist["columns"]=("1")
itemlist.column("1",width=50)
itemlist.heading("1",text="Item ID")
itemlist.bind("<Double-1>", select)
itemlist.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

# Nametag
Label(root,text="Name:").grid(row=3,column=0)

# 'Save' Button
saveButton=Button(text="Save")
saveButton.bind("<Button-1>",savebind)
saveButton.grid(row=1,column=0)

# 'Add New' button
newItemButton=Button(text="New Event")
newItemButton.bind("<Button-1>",newItem)
newItemButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

# Name entry text field
itemNameEntry=Entry(root,width=25)
itemNameEntry.grid(row=3,column=1)

# Submit Button
submitButton=Button(root,width=25,text="Submit")
submitButton.grid(row=4,column=1)
submitButton.bind("<Button-1>",submit)

# Begin loading
load()

# Start GUI
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: set the actual background property of the widget to the same colour as your canvas background, its not a great fix but it works

Comment: That was already mentioned in an answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: the answer mentioned `highlightbackground` try just `background`

Comment: Same result `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-background"`

Comment: dont use the dash

Comment: I didn't use the dash. That's just the output of the error message.

Comment: can i refer you to nbro's answer on here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912250/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-ttk-combobox

Answer (score 1):

Configure your widgets to use `highlightbackground = 'white'` (or whatever your background colour is) and set your `highlightthickness=0`

This should remove the grey outline.

EG

```
itemNameEntry=Entry(root,width=25, highlightbackground='white')
itemNameEntry.config(highlightthickness=0)
```

Comment: I get `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-highlightbackground"` and `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-highlightthickness"` when running.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: looks like its a mac issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084321/tkinter-leaving-borders-around-widgets

Comment: I think they're separate, the colour looks different.

Comment: you are comparing 2 different type of widgets there though?

Comment: Yes - but the colour is the same on all widgets in the program, including a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use widget.config(highlightthickness=0) or pass this parameter in widget constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing tkinter.ttk you need to import that first, then import tkinter.

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import *
```

Comment: This most likely doesn't fix the issue.